# Why do I get the "undeclared identifier" error in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I copied the below code from the public library on tradingview.com. It appears to have been written on an older version of pine script. I am currently using version 4 and I feel the error is because I am calling the function smma from within itself as a recursive function but I am not sure how to fix the error.

```
study("My Strategy", overlay=true)

//SUITABLE FOR INTRADAY IN BANK NIFTY 5MIN 10MIN AND 15MIN APPLICAPABLE IN ANY TIME FRAME
//TEST YOUR STRATEGY
//borrowed this concept from someone else and modified it for our needs
//teach me pine i wanna learn from you =>skgs01@gmail.com
smma(src, length) =>
    smma = na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma

jawLength = input(13, "Jaw Length")
jawOffset = input(8, "Jaw Offset")

jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)

plot(jaw, "Jaw", color=color.blue, offset=jawOffset)
```

Comment: You should define `smma` before you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baris Yakut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7209631/baris-yakut) is right. You should declare your variable before using it. Like this:

```
//@version=4
study("My Strategy", overlay=true)

//SUITABLE FOR INTRADAY IN BANK NIFTY 5MIN 10MIN AND 15MIN APPLICAPABLE IN ANY TIME FRAME
//TEST YOUR STRATEGY
//borrowed this concept from someone else and modified it for our needs
//teach me pine i wanna learn from you =>skgs01@gmail.com
smma(src, length) =>
    var float smma = na
    smma := na(smma[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (smma[1] * (length - 1) + src) / length
    smma

jawLength = input(13, "Jaw Length")
jawOffset = input(8, "Jaw Offset")

jaw = smma(hl2, jawLength)

plot(jaw, "Jaw", color=color.blue, offset=jawOffset)
```